# Real Time File Scanning using Google DLP for more than 0.5MB size files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-dlp, google-dl-platform

Its mentioned in google cloud documentation that maximum 0.5MB file size can be inspect/scanned as in memory files. For file size greater than lets say 2 MB, we need to upload the file on cloud storage and read/inspect it from there only. I see the code logic mentioned in the doc is not real-time processing. Is it possible to do real time scanning for larger file sizes here? Thanks

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/inspecting-storage#inspecting-gcs

Comment: The work around for this problem is to divide the file into chunks and do the real time scanning and also if it’s too important in your case you can raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) with google cloud requesting to add this functionality. Hope your issue will get resolved

Comment: Sure. I checked with Google cloud technical support, they already have this kind of request to work upon. Also for dividing the files into chunks, is it possible for all kinds of files? Like in my case I have jpg, docx, png, text etc file extensions.

Comment: you can split the docx, text files and for img, jpg, png files you can compress them(though you need to compromise on quality).

Answer (score 0):

How big do you need to go? Can you break up the files and send parts of them?

Comment: Around 5 MB. I have all categories of files including images. Is it possible to split up?

Comment: At the moment we are restricting request size so that we can meet latency and reliability requirements, so for files as big as 5mb you'll need to use GCS for now.